# PrimeNG panel menu not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I would integrate PrimeNG Panel menu to my application.

In `modules.ts` I import `PanelMenuModule` and `MenuModule`

```
import {LeftMenuComponent } from './left-menu/left-menu.component';
import {PanelMenuModule} from 'primeng/panelmenu';
import {MenuModule} from 'primeng/primeng';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    CardModule,
    PanelMenuModule,
    MenuModule

  ],
  declarations: [

  LeftMenuComponent],
  providers:  [
  ],
  exports :[
    AutoCompleteModule,
    CardModule,
    LeftMenuComponent,
    PanelMenuModule,
    MenuModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then In my component I import `MenuItem`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-menu',
  templateUrl: './left-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-menu.component.css']
})
export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
 items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
          ... all menu data like the official example
        ]
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>
<p>TEST</p>
```

then I call this component in another module:

```
<app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
```

I also import the `SharedModule` in the module where I call the left menu component.

What I see in screen is only `TEST` word but not the menu.

I'm using PrimeNG 5.2.0 version.

How can I make Menu Panel working ?

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: I found the solution... I have two ngOnInit()..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. I include BrowserAnimationsModule in my `app.module.ts` and you have to install `npm install @angular/animations --save`

```
 import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';  

  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule ...
```

Comment: Still required with the version 16.5.1 ...

Answer (score -1):

Import in app.module.ts :

```
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/panel';
import { PanelMenuModule } from 'primeng/panelmenu';
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to add the module call in appmodule.

```
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
```